# How to use an input field to permanently save to a webpage?

Tags: java, php, html, input, hyperlink

First of all, I'm not a programming expert. I'm fluent in VB, functional with html & php, & somewhat fluent with java.

I have created a password protected side of my business' website that basically has commonly needed reference material & alot of organized links to other websites that we frequently use. Right now, if I want to add a new link, I have to go into the html and code the button. (side note: bookmark syncronization via xMarks is what we have been using. While it's functional, I need something that can be more easily accessed on multiple computers, sometimes even public computers & computers owned by clients, so I don't want to be limited by xMarks...we basically store URLs in notes on our smartphones so we can type them in when we need them...archaic, I know)

It seems that it would be possible to simply have a form. One field for the URL, one field for the title, and when I click submit it would be permanently added as a button on that page...but I can't even really figure out where to start. I feel like this is probably a job for Java, but I just don't know what direction to go.

You don't have to write the code for me (by all means, if you have the desire, feel free) I just need to know what direction to go!

Comment: You can do this in PHP. You'll need a database, and to query that. Have a div on your site where you print out all data inside a certain table (say called "urls"). Then every time you get a new one, have a form that updates that table. Every time you load the page, you will load the data from the database, keeping you up to date

Comment: FYI, this type of feature is built into any common CMS--Joomla, WordPress, etc. You haven't told us what platform your site is built on, but maybe you can avoid reinventing wheels.

Comment: I actually did pretty much this same thing with my website using PHP.  I have a password protected area that I can update my database via various forms.  One is actually for urls that then get outputted to a web page.  Very handy.  Quentin lays it out pretty well below.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for "any programming language" (that is supported by your server, or which you are willing to add support for to your server).

Of your tags, you could use Java or PHP. My personal preference would probably be to Perl or Python.

The basics would be:

HTML form submitting to a server side program that adds the data to a database. For a low traffic system like that, that database could be SQLite.

Plus: Server side program that generates a list of links from the database. It would query the database for all the links (possibly adding paging when the list got to a certain size) then loop over the results and output the HTML for each one.

Using a template language inside your programming language would be wise. Make sure you look up how to defend yourself from SQL Injection and XSS.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using PHP